# After adding a csv file, the links in the html file do not work anymore

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have stopped working links in html after adding style.css, when I remove style.css all links work again. No matter how I add links they do not work anyway. I have attached the index.html and style.css file below, Any help with the code would be great!
index.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- stars -->
    <div class="stars">
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
        <div class="star"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- head -->
    <header>
        <div>
            <a href="index.html" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 80px;">
                <img src="media/logoo.png" alt="logo" style="width: 150px; height: auto; clip: rect(0px, 100px, 50px, 0px);">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="main"><a href="https://fixedfloat.com/about" style="text-decoration: none;">About</a></p>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #0d1d31 0%, #0c0d13 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #5e9ce2;
}

.stars {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.star {
  --star-color: var(--primary-color);
  --star-tail-length: 6em;
  --star-tail-height: 2px;
  --star-width: calc(var(--star-tail-length) / 6);
  --fall-duration: 9s;
  --tail-fade-duration: var(--fall-duration);
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--top-offset);
  left: 0;
  width: var(--star-tail-length);
  height: var(--star-tail-height);
  color: var(--star-color);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, currentColor, transparent);
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 6px currentColor);
  transform: translate3d(104em, 0, 0);
  animation: fall var(--fall-duration) var(--fall-delay) linear infinite, tail-fade var(--tail-fade-duration) var(--fall-delay) ease-out infinite;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .star {
    animation: fall var(--fall-duration) var(--fall-delay) linear infinite;
  }
}
.star:nth-child(1) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.42em;
  --top-offset: 91.42vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.883s;
  --fall-delay: 9.243s;
}
.star:nth-child(2) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.65em;
  --top-offset: 35.2vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.348s;
  --fall-delay: 9.487s;
}
.star:nth-child(3) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.5em;
  --top-offset: 44.59vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.189s;
  --fall-delay: 4.048s;
}
.star:nth-child(4) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.05em;
  --top-offset: 52.39vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.227s;
  --fall-delay: 2.644s;
}
.star:nth-child(5) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.66em;
  --top-offset: 13.38vh;
  --fall-duration: 6.508s;
  --fall-delay: 4.468s;
}
.star:nth-child(6) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.4em;
  --top-offset: 16.82vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.272s;
  --fall-delay: 3.234s;
}
.star:nth-child(7) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.21em;
  --top-offset: 54.97vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.353s;
  --fall-delay: 5.9s;
}
.star:nth-child(8) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.15em;
  --top-offset: 78.08vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.137s;
  --fall-delay: 7.126s;
}
.star:nth-child(9) {
  --star-tail-length: 7em;
  --top-offset: 73.39vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.93s;
  --fall-delay: 6.951s;
}
.star:nth-child(10) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.48em;
  --top-offset: 98.16vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.745s;
  --fall-delay: 2.463s;
}
.star:nth-child(11) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.31em;
  --top-offset: 47.97vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.58s;
  --fall-delay: 1.812s;
}
.star:nth-child(12) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.2em;
  --top-offset: 3.8vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.272s;
  --fall-delay: 1.493s;
}
.star:nth-child(13) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.44em;
  --top-offset: 66.21vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.307s;
  --fall-delay: 8.897s;
}
.star:nth-child(14) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.61em;
  --top-offset: 57.55vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.163s;
  --fall-delay: 7.239s;
}
.star:nth-child(15) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.35em;
  --top-offset: 80.38vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.348s;
  --fall-delay: 2.744s;
}
.star:nth-child(16) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.99em;
  --top-offset: 52.43vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.049s;
  --fall-delay: 6.638s;
}
.star:nth-child(17) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.63em;
  --top-offset: 16.33vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.944s;
  --fall-delay: 4.792s;
}
.star:nth-child(18) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.21em;
  --top-offset: 36.16vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.625s;
  --fall-delay: 0.086s;
}
.star:nth-child(19) {
  --star-tail-length: 7em;
  --top-offset: 86.83vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.006s;
  --fall-delay: 7.969s;
}
.star:nth-child(20) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.49em;
  --top-offset: 71vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.418s;
  --fall-delay: 5.522s;
}
.star:nth-child(21) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.39em;
  --top-offset: 57.2vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.747s;
  --fall-delay: 6.503s;
}
.star:nth-child(22) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.06em;
  --top-offset: 3.87vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.784s;
  --fall-delay: 1.126s;
}
.star:nth-child(23) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.49em;
  --top-offset: 61.12vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.994s;
  --fall-delay: 6.287s;
}
.star:nth-child(24) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.1em;
  --top-offset: 73.65vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.455s;
  --fall-delay: 6.274s;
}
.star:nth-child(25) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.14em;
  --top-offset: 52.58vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.936s;
  --fall-delay: 4.428s;
}
.star:nth-child(26) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.79em;
  --top-offset: 0.02vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.395s;
  --fall-delay: 3.252s;
}
.star:nth-child(27) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.76em;
  --top-offset: 79.27vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.931s;
  --fall-delay: 6.989s;
}
.star:nth-child(28) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.03em;
  --top-offset: 20.34vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.47s;
  --fall-delay: 3.472s;
}
.star:nth-child(29) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.7em;
  --top-offset: 41.33vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.859s;
  --fall-delay: 5.425s;
}
.star:nth-child(30) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.31em;
  --top-offset: 5.13vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.906s;
  --fall-delay: 6.664s;
}
.star:nth-child(31) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.72em;
  --top-offset: 56.37vh;
  --fall-duration: 6.21s;
  --fall-delay: 2.698s;
}
.star:nth-child(32) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.42em;
  --top-offset: 44.21vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.828s;
  --fall-delay: 0.776s;
}
.star:nth-child(33) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.63em;
  --top-offset: 78.63vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.743s;
  --fall-delay: 0.937s;
}
.star:nth-child(34) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.22em;
  --top-offset: 69.82vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.973s;
  --fall-delay: 4.881s;
}
.star:nth-child(35) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.72em;
  --top-offset: 26.81vh;
  --fall-duration: 6.534s;
  --fall-delay: 9.414s;
}
.star:nth-child(36) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.84em;
  --top-offset: 1.07vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.474s;
  --fall-delay: 8.621s;
}
.star:nth-child(37) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.52em;
  --top-offset: 61.71vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.469s;
  --fall-delay: 7.25s;
}
.star:nth-child(38) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.83em;
  --top-offset: 83.01vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.611s;
  --fall-delay: 6.944s;
}
.star:nth-child(39) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.47em;
  --top-offset: 36.06vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.648s;
  --fall-delay: 0.575s;
}
.star:nth-child(40) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.18em;
  --top-offset: 26.24vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.058s;
  --fall-delay: 9.153s;
}
.star:nth-child(41) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.47em;
  --top-offset: 21.26vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.039s;
  --fall-delay: 2.669s;
}
.star:nth-child(42) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.48em;
  --top-offset: 6.51vh;
  --fall-duration: 6.084s;
  --fall-delay: 0.54s;
}
.star:nth-child(43) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.18em;
  --top-offset: 23.12vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.773s;
  --fall-delay: 4.242s;
}
.star:nth-child(44) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.56em;
  --top-offset: 64.95vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.882s;
  --fall-delay: 0.671s;
}
.star:nth-child(45) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.49em;
  --top-offset: 62.5vh;
  --fall-duration: 6.65s;
  --fall-delay: 7.761s;
}
.star:nth-child(46) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.12em;
  --top-offset: 46.39vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.437s;
  --fall-delay: 6.915s;
}
.star:nth-child(47) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.97em;
  --top-offset: 60.45vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.868s;
  --fall-delay: 9.445s;
}
.star:nth-child(48) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.19em;
  --top-offset: 21.42vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.275s;
  --fall-delay: 2.53s;
}
.star:nth-child(49) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.3em;
  --top-offset: 36.19vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.297s;
  --fall-delay: 1.341s;
}
.star:nth-child(50) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.31em;
  --top-offset: 70.3vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.481s;
  --fall-delay: 6.827s;
}
.star::before, .star::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: calc(var(--star-width) / -2);
  width: var(--star-width);
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, currentColor, transparent);
  border-radius: inherit;
  animation: blink 2s linear infinite;
}
.star::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.star::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes fall {
  to {
    transform: translate3d(-30em, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes tail-fade {
  0%, 50% {
    width: var(--star-tail-length);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70%, 80% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
}/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

the link is not clickable for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra closing `</div>` after the stars *div* and adding `z-index` in your *stars* class will fix the problem.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #0d1d31 0%, #0c0d13 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #5e9ce2;
}

.stars {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.star {
  --star-color: var(--primary-color);
  --star-tail-length: 6em;
  --star-tail-height: 2px;
  --star-width: calc(var(--star-tail-length) / 6);
  --fall-duration: 9s;
  --tail-fade-duration: var(--fall-duration);
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--top-offset);
  left: 0;
  width: var(--star-tail-length);
  height: var(--star-tail-height);
  color: var(--star-color);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, currentColor, transparent);
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 6px currentColor);
  transform: translate3d(104em, 0, 0);
  animation: fall var(--fall-duration) var(--fall-delay) linear infinite, tail-fade var(--tail-fade-duration) var(--fall-delay) ease-out infinite;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .star {
    animation: fall var(--fall-duration) var(--fall-delay) linear infinite;
  }
}
.star:nth-child(1) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.42em;
  --top-offset: 91.42vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.883s;
  --fall-delay: 9.243s;
}
.star:nth-child(2) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.65em;
  --top-offset: 35.2vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.348s;
  --fall-delay: 9.487s;
}
.star:nth-child(3) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.5em;
  --top-offset: 44.59vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.189s;
  --fall-delay: 4.048s;
}
.star:nth-child(4) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.05em;
  --top-offset: 52.39vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.227s;
  --fall-delay: 2.644s;
}
.star:nth-child(5) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.66em;
  --top-offset: 13.38vh;
  --fall-duration: 6.508s;
  --fall-delay: 4.468s;
}
.star:nth-child(6) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.4em;
  --top-offset: 16.82vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.272s;
  --fall-delay: 3.234s;
}
.star:nth-child(7) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.21em;
  --top-offset: 54.97vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.353s;
  --fall-delay: 5.9s;
}
.star:nth-child(8) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.15em;
  --top-offset: 78.08vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.137s;
  --fall-delay: 7.126s;
}
.star:nth-child(9) {
  --star-tail-length: 7em;
  --top-offset: 73.39vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.93s;
  --fall-delay: 6.951s;
}
.star:nth-child(10) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.48em;
  --top-offset: 98.16vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.745s;
  --fall-delay: 2.463s;
}
.star:nth-child(11) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.31em;
  --top-offset: 47.97vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.58s;
  --fall-delay: 1.812s;
}
.star:nth-child(12) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.2em;
  --top-offset: 3.8vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.272s;
  --fall-delay: 1.493s;
}
.star:nth-child(13) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.44em;
  --top-offset: 66.21vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.307s;
  --fall-delay: 8.897s;
}
.star:nth-child(14) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.61em;
  --top-offset: 57.55vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.163s;
  --fall-delay: 7.239s;
}
.star:nth-child(15) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.35em;
  --top-offset: 80.38vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.348s;
  --fall-delay: 2.744s;
}
.star:nth-child(16) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.99em;
  --top-offset: 52.43vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.049s;
  --fall-delay: 6.638s;
}
.star:nth-child(17) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.63em;
  --top-offset: 16.33vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.944s;
  --fall-delay: 4.792s;
}
.star:nth-child(18) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.21em;
  --top-offset: 36.16vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.625s;
  --fall-delay: 0.086s;
}
.star:nth-child(19) {
  --star-tail-length: 7em;
  --top-offset: 86.83vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.006s;
  --fall-delay: 7.969s;
}
.star:nth-child(20) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.49em;
  --top-offset: 71vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.418s;
  --fall-delay: 5.522s;
}
.star:nth-child(21) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.39em;
  --top-offset: 57.2vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.747s;
  --fall-delay: 6.503s;
}
.star:nth-child(22) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.06em;
  --top-offset: 3.87vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.784s;
  --fall-delay: 1.126s;
}
.star:nth-child(23) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.49em;
  --top-offset: 61.12vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.994s;
  --fall-delay: 6.287s;
}
.star:nth-child(24) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.1em;
  --top-offset: 73.65vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.455s;
  --fall-delay: 6.274s;
}
.star:nth-child(25) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.14em;
  --top-offset: 52.58vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.936s;
  --fall-delay: 4.428s;
}
.star:nth-child(26) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.79em;
  --top-offset: 0.02vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.395s;
  --fall-delay: 3.252s;
}
.star:nth-child(27) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.76em;
  --top-offset: 79.27vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.931s;
  --fall-delay: 6.989s;
}
.star:nth-child(28) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.03em;
  --top-offset: 20.34vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.47s;
  --fall-delay: 3.472s;
}
.star:nth-child(29) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.7em;
  --top-offset: 41.33vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.859s;
  --fall-delay: 5.425s;
}
.star:nth-child(30) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.31em;
  --top-offset: 5.13vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.906s;
  --fall-delay: 6.664s;
}
.star:nth-child(31) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.72em;
  --top-offset: 56.37vh;
  --fall-duration: 6.21s;
  --fall-delay: 2.698s;
}
.star:nth-child(32) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.42em;
  --top-offset: 44.21vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.828s;
  --fall-delay: 0.776s;
}
.star:nth-child(33) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.63em;
  --top-offset: 78.63vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.743s;
  --fall-delay: 0.937s;
}
.star:nth-child(34) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.22em;
  --top-offset: 69.82vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.973s;
  --fall-delay: 4.881s;
}
.star:nth-child(35) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.72em;
  --top-offset: 26.81vh;
  --fall-duration: 6.534s;
  --fall-delay: 9.414s;
}
.star:nth-child(36) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.84em;
  --top-offset: 1.07vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.474s;
  --fall-delay: 8.621s;
}
.star:nth-child(37) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.52em;
  --top-offset: 61.71vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.469s;
  --fall-delay: 7.25s;
}
.star:nth-child(38) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.83em;
  --top-offset: 83.01vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.611s;
  --fall-delay: 6.944s;
}
.star:nth-child(39) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.47em;
  --top-offset: 36.06vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.648s;
  --fall-delay: 0.575s;
}
.star:nth-child(40) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.18em;
  --top-offset: 26.24vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.058s;
  --fall-delay: 9.153s;
}
.star:nth-child(41) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.47em;
  --top-offset: 21.26vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.039s;
  --fall-delay: 2.669s;
}
.star:nth-child(42) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.48em;
  --top-offset: 6.51vh;
  --fall-duration: 6.084s;
  --fall-delay: 0.54s;
}
.star:nth-child(43) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.18em;
  --top-offset: 23.12vh;
  --fall-duration: 10.773s;
  --fall-delay: 4.242s;
}
.star:nth-child(44) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.56em;
  --top-offset: 64.95vh;
  --fall-duration: 9.882s;
  --fall-delay: 0.671s;
}
.star:nth-child(45) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.49em;
  --top-offset: 62.5vh;
  --fall-duration: 6.65s;
  --fall-delay: 7.761s;
}
.star:nth-child(46) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.12em;
  --top-offset: 46.39vh;
  --fall-duration: 7.437s;
  --fall-delay: 6.915s;
}
.star:nth-child(47) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.97em;
  --top-offset: 60.45vh;
  --fall-duration: 8.868s;
  --fall-delay: 9.445s;
}
.star:nth-child(48) {
  --star-tail-length: 6.19em;
  --top-offset: 21.42vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.275s;
  --fall-delay: 2.53s;
}
.star:nth-child(49) {
  --star-tail-length: 7.3em;
  --top-offset: 36.19vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.297s;
  --fall-delay: 1.341s;
}
.star:nth-child(50) {
  --star-tail-length: 5.31em;
  --top-offset: 70.3vh;
  --fall-duration: 11.481s;
  --fall-delay: 6.827s;
}
.star::before, .star::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: calc(var(--star-width) / -2);
  width: var(--star-width);
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, currentColor, transparent);
  border-radius: inherit;
  animation: blink 2s linear infinite;
}
.star::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.star::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes fall {
  to {
    transform: translate3d(-30em, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes tail-fade {
  0%, 50% {
    width: var(--star-tail-length);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70%, 80% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
}/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!-- stars -->
<div class="stars">
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
</div>

<!-- head -->
<header>
    <div>
        <a href="index.html" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 80px;">
            <img src="media/logoo.png" alt="logo" style="width: 150px; height: auto; clip: rect(0px, 100px, 50px, 0px);">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="main"><a href="https://fixedfloat.com/about" style="text-decoration: none;">About</a></p>
    </div>
</header>
```